# Delphi 10.4.2 and Delphi 11.0 cannot debug -

Tags: delphi, debugging

I cannot run Delphi in Debug.  was previously running in Delphi 10.4.1
Now running both Delphi 10.4.2 in Windows 64-bit FMX and it gave the dreaded error "Unable to create process, 'c:\Win64\Debug\project1.exe'.

I googled.  Some mentioned that it can be firewall setting (see below, which was automatically created).  Some mentioned that it has to do with bds.exe permissions.  One person ever mentioned to try running in Administrator mode.  I tried all but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[image: Firewall Incoming connections setting]

Comment: I would recommend you also check your Anti Virus Software. It would not be the first time that some AV software started marking applications compiled with Delphi as being potentially malicious. I have experienced such scenario in the past where my AV software would more my application executable into Quarantine just after it was compiled but before it could be ran by Delphi. And Delphi would spit out the same error to me.

Comment: The 64 bit debugger has never worked reliably. I tend to do all my debugging in 32 bit even if our customers always use the 64 bit version of the program.

Comment: @SilverWarior the executable is there... I don't have the AV turned on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the 64-bit has worked all along till 10.4.1  only when I upgraded to 10.4.2 and 11.0 did this error pop up.  Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the Windows Firewall.  Bring up the Control Panel, click System and Security, Windows Defender Firewall, Allow app through Windows Firewall.

Click [Change Settings] button.

The Embarcadero Debugger Kernel is originally installed as:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\dbkw64_28_0.exe

Remove it, and add in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\dbkw64_28_0.exe

Restart Delphi.  Bingo! It now works